# Use Python Loop to create NX3 matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am quite new to Python. The ongoing project involves creating a N X 3 matrix from a set of numbers, numbers∈[0,1,2] where each row is to be filled by a combination of these numbers, like [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2]...[2,2,2].

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
numbers = []

x = 0
while x < 2:
    y = 0
    while y < 2:
        z = 0
        while z < 2:
            numbers.append((x,y,z))
            z += 1
        numbers.append((x,y,z))
        y += 1    
    numbers.append((x,y,z))
    x += 1
print(np.asarray(numbers))
```

But the output is only:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 2 2]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 0 2]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 2]
 [1 2 2]]
```

It should contain 27 rows. It can also be done using `itertools.product` though. But how can the code be rewritten to get all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

The quicker and easy to read code is:

```
result = np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1,2], repeat=3)))
```

(don't re-invent the wheel if you can use a library function).

But if you insist on your 3 nested loops, run:

```
numbers = []
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        for z in range(3):
            numbers.append((x,y,z))
result = np.array(numbers)
```

The errors in your code are that:

- it should contain only the most inner `numbers.append((x,y,z))`,
- all 3 loops should be `while ... <= 2:`

But my code is shorter.

Comment: Using `while` loop over for has the advantage of setting the increment to any real number. `while ... <= 2:` will also include 3 as the increment is +1.